# Removing 'AllFiles' from file types when using uigetfile

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm using uigetfile with a custom set of FilterSpecs. Here is the sentence:

```
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile({'*.wav';'*.mp3'},'Open Audio File');
```

As you can see my FilterSpec is `{'*.wav';'*.mp3'}` and this works perfectly fine. My problem is simple, is just that matlab is always appending `AllFiles(*.*)` to my FilterSpecs. I have searched in Matlab docs and it literally states:
**"uigetfile appends All Files(*.*) to the file types when FilterSpec is a string."**, but the problem is that I don't see another way of specifying a custom FilterSpec without using strings.Sorry if this results in a dumb question.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to (easily) remove the 'AllFiles' from `uigetfile()` since it's always added by MATLAB.

If you really want to do it, you have to copy the `uigetputfile_helper()` code (to 
`MYuigetputfile_helper()` for example) and change it. And then you call it from your `MYuigetfile()` - same idea here.

The change would be around lines 311 and 319 in my version from `uigetputfile_helper()`, i.e.

```
% Now add 'All Files' appropriately.
if (addAllFiles)
  % If a string, create a cell array and append '*.*'.
  if (~iscell(returned_filter))
    returned_filter = {returned_filter; '*.*'};
    % If it is a cell array without descriptors, add '*.*'.
  elseif (size(returned_filter, 2) == 1)
     returned_filter{end+1} = '*.*';
  end
end
```

Hope that helps... have fun!

Answer (score 0):

If you back up a few lines from the previous poster's answer, you'll see a comment:

> We want to add 'All Files' in all cases unless we have a cell array with descriptors.

This comment is on line 245 of uigetputfile_helper for me.  Simply describe your file types at the time you call `uigetfile`, and you won't see `All Files (*.*)`

Example:

```
[fname,pname] = uigetfile({'*.m','MATLAB Code (*.m)';'*.mat','MATLAB Data (*.mat)'});
```